# The for loop rewrites all values of array in structure C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have a problem with assigning values to a string array which is a field in my struct. In this case, I am also using an array of this structs. When I assign values without for loop, everything works fine. But the problem occurs in the for loop. I have printed all assignments and they are OK. But the problem actually is, that the every assignment actually rewrites all array positions in all structures of that field.

```
struct ship 
{
int length;
char *fields[4];
};

struct ship shipPositions[6];

for(int h=0; h < length; h++) //goes from 0 to 3 for first two values
        {

            char c = getCharFromInt(begin + h); //my function which works fine; begin = 2;
            char coord[3] = "$";
            append(coord, c); // also works fine
            append(coord,ships[i][1]);
            shipPositions[i].fields[h] = coord;
            printf("shipPositions[%d].fields[%d] = %s\n", i,h,shipPositions[i].fields[h]);


        }

printf("Position: %s\n",shipPositions[0].fields[0]);
printf("Position: %s\n",shipPositions[0].fields[1]);

/* it prints assignments and then on the first two values after for loop
shipPositions[0].fields[0] = $C2
shipPositions[0].fields[1] = $D2
shipPositions[0].fields[2] = $E2
shipPositions[1].fields[0] = $F0
shipPositions[1].fields[1] = $G0
shipPositions[1].fields[2] = $H0
shipPositions[5].fields[0] = $H8
shipPositions[5].fields[1] = $I8
Position: $I8
Position: $I8
*/
```

And when I simulate first two cases of for loop, everything is also fine:

```
char c1 = getCharFromInt(2 + 0);
char coord1[3] = "$";
append(coord1, c1);
append(coord1,ships[0][1]);
shipPositions[0].fields[0] = coord1;
printf("shipPositions[%d].fields[%d] = %s\n", 0,0,shipPositions[0].fields[0]);

char c2 = getCharFromInt(2 + 1);
char coord2[3] = "$";
append(coord2, c2);
append(coord2,ships[0][1]);
shipPositions[0].fields[1] = coord2;
printf("shipPositions[%d].fields[%d] = %s\n", 0,1,shipPositions[0].fields[1]);

printf("Position: %s\n",shipPositions[0].fields[0]);
printf("Position: %s\n",shipPositions[0].fields[1]);

/*
shipPositions[0].fields[0] = $C2
shipPositions[0].fields[1] = $D2
Position: $C2
Position: $D2


*/
```

Comment: It is because you've got a *pointer to a variable* that *dies at the end of the block*. Also, perhaps you shouldn't *strings* for fields like that, instead use a structure of `struct Position { int x, y; }` say.

Comment: Thanks Antti for the answer. Can you please write me how should I fix this loop. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46969661/2371524)

Comment: I reopened the question though. [This answer does tell why it happens and how to fix in general case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895628/array-members-overwritten-with-last-element), but the general case is not really appropriate here. Use a `struct` instead of a string for coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's 2 problems with your code.

Firstly when you declare `char coord[3]`, you're creating a string of 2 characters long because you also need to include a NUL character to terminate the string. But you're storing 3 characters in it, so you need to declare it as `char coord[4]`.

You don't provide the code for `append`, but you do need to remember to assign the NUL character if it isn't doing it for you ie `coord[3]='\0'`

Secondly, `coord` only exists as a variable for each iteration of the loop, but the memory it occupies will still remain. When you assign `coord` to `shipPositions[i].fields[h]` you're assigning a pointer to the memory, not the actual contents of the string. When an iteration of the loop finishes, `coord` ceases to exist and your code can use the memory it occupied for other things (like the next instance of `coord`) overwriting the value you expect to find in `shipPositions[i].fields[h]`.

You should declare `fields` to be an array of arrays like `char fields[4][4]` and then when you want to stash the contents of `coord` you would use `strcpy` ie `strcpy(shipPositions[i].fields[h],coord)`. That way you "own" the memory you're storing the value in and it won't get overwritten once `coord` no longer exists.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I appreciate it !